# Get count of multiple sections of a column

Tags: vba, excel, rowcount

I have a table like this:

```
A1          B1 Team 1   C1 Team 2   D1 Team 3
A2 Name     B2 A        C2 B        D2 C
A3          B3 D        C3 E        D3 F
A4          B4 G        C4          D4 H
A5 School   B5 AB       C5 CD       D5
A6          B6 GH       C6 EF       D6
A7          B7          C7 IJ       D7
```

I'm trying to write a macro to get the count of the non blank rows as follows:

```
A1          B1 Team 1   C1 Team 2   D1 Team 3
A2 Name     B2 A        C2 B        D2 C
A3          B3 D        C3 E        D3 F
A4          B4 G        C4          D4 H
A5          B5 3        C5 2        D5 3
A6 School   B6 AB       C6 CD       D6
A7          B7 GH       C7 EF       D7
A8          B8          C8 IJ       D8 
A9          B9 2        C9 3        D9 0
```

where the 5th and the 9th rows give the count of non blank rows.
I need to do this using Macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the COUNTA function in VBA. With dynamic output rows, I strongly suggest labelling these rows so that the code can easily find them. In this case, I've done so by putting "Name Count" in cell A5, and "School Count" in cell A9 (in the second table that you posted). These could be in any row you want.  The code will find them as long they are in column A.

For future reference, using named ranges would be a much cleaner and more efficient way of doing this.

```
Sub der()

'Declare and set worksheet object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Worksheet name here

Dim nameOutRow As Integer, schoolOutRow As Integer
Dim ns As Integer, ne As Integer, ss As Integer, se As Integer

'Find the Output rows
nameOutRow = Application.Match("Name Count", ws.Columns(1), 0)
schoolOutRow = Application.Match("School Count", ws.Columns(1), 0) 

'Determine Name count range
ns = Application.Match("Name", ws.Columns(1), 0) 'name start row
ne = nameOutRow - 1 'name end row

'School count range
ss = Application.Match("School", ws.Columns(1), 0) 'school start row
se = schoolOutRow - 1 'school end row

'Names
ws.Range("B" & nameOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("B" & ns & ":B" & ne))
ws.Range("C" & nameOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("C" & ns & ":C" & ne))
ws.Range("D" & nameOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("D" & ns & ":D" & ne))

'Schools
ws.Range("B" & schoolOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("B" & ss & ":B" & se))
ws.Range("C" & schoolOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("C" & ss & ":C" & se))
ws.Range("D" & schoolOutRow) = Application.CountA(ws.Range("D" & ss & ":D" & se))


End Sub
```

Comment: Actually the entries in the columns B, C, D are dynamic. Hence I can't hard-code the range to B5, C5, etc. @oortCloud Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Thank you @oortCloud ! There's just one problem. i'm getting a type mismatch error on `nameOutRow = Application.Match("Name Count", ws.Columns(1), 0)` Can you please help?

Comment: My first thought is check the exact spelling of **Name Count** on your worksheet. Application.match should deliver the same result as the match worksheet function. You can test it using the following formula in a cell: =match("Name Count",A:A,0)   If this works, then Application.match should work.

Comment: Thank you @oortCloud !! You are amazing! :)